# Tikzpicture doesn't display correctly

Tags: pgfplots, floats, bar-chart

I'm new to LaTeX and am struggling with a problem that I cannot fix.

How do I:

1. get ride of all the number inside the bar,
2. get rid of the 120% on the y bar and have it start from 0%, and
3. get the bar to display correct proportion (currently the 52% looks the same as 37%).

Below is my MWE, thanks a lot.

My MWE is

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
    ybar stacked,
    bar width=47pt,
    nodes near coords,
    enlargelimits=0.5,
    legend style={at={(1.2, 0.5)},
      anchor=west,legend columns=1.7},
    symbolic x coords={A, B},
    xtick=data,
    x tick label style={anchor=north},
    yticklabel={\pgfmathparse{\tick*100}\pgfmathprintnumber{\pgfmathresult}\%},
    ]

\addplot+[ybar] plot coordinates {(A,0.52) (B,0.45)} ;
\addplot+[ybar] plot coordinates {(A,0.37) (B,0.45)} ;
\addplot+[ybar] plot coordinates {(A,0.11) (B,0.1)} ;
\legend{\strut Teritary degree, \strut High school diploma, \strut Less than high school}
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
```

Comment: Hi, welcomme. Your code is not compileable.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have added those numbers with the `nodes near coords` options. The purpose of that option is precisely to add things like the y-values above plot points/bars.

The other part is mostly a matter of setting the axis limits. You need `ymin=0` to make the y-axis start at zero, and change `enlargelimits` to `enlarge x limits` so the axis limits are extended only in the x-direction.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{pgfplots}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
    ybar stacked,
    bar width=47pt,
%    nodes near coords, % removed
    ymin=0, % added
    enlarge x limits=0.5, % modified
    legend style={at={(1.2, 0.5)},
      anchor=west,legend columns=1.7},
    symbolic x coords={A, B},
    xtick=data,
    x tick label style={anchor=north},
    yticklabel={\pgfmathparse{\tick*100}\pgfmathprintnumber{\pgfmathresult}\%},
    ]

\addplot+[ybar] plot coordinates {(A,0.52) (B,0.45)} ;
\addplot+[ybar] plot coordinates {(A,0.37) (B,0.45)} ;
\addplot+[ybar] plot coordinates {(A,0.11) (B,0.1)} ;
\legend{\strut Teritary degree, \strut High school diploma, \strut Less than high school}
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Great, thanks very much! You saved my whole afternoon trying to figure it out!